# Redis - why is redis-server decreasing in memory?

Tags: redis

I'm running Redis on windows and have noticed that the size of `redis-server.exe` decreases over time. When I open Redis, it reads from a dump file and loads all of the hashed key values into memory to about **1.4 GB**. However, over time, the amount of memory that `redis-server.exe` takes up decreases. I have seen it go down to less than **100 MB**.

The only reason that I could see this happening is that the keys are expiring and leaving memory, however I have set Redis up so that they never expire. I have also made sure that I have given enough memory.

Some of my settings include:

```
maxmemory 2gb

maxmemory-policy noeviction

hash-max-zipmap-entries 512

hash-max-zipmap-value 64

activerehashing no
```

If it's of interest, when I first loaded the keys into Redis, I did it through Python like so:

```
r.hset(key, field, value)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I want the keys to be there forever.

This is my output from the INFO command right after I first run it:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> INFO
redis_version:2.4.6
redis_git_sha1:26cdd13a
redis_git_dirty:0
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:winsock2
gcc_version:4.6.1
process_id:9092
uptime_in_seconds:69
uptime_in_days:0
lru_clock:248011
used_cpu_sys:3.34
used_cpu_user:10.06
used_cpu_sys_children:0.00
used_cpu_user_children:0.00
connected_clients:1
connected_slaves:0
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0
used_memory:1129560232
used_memory_human:1.05G
used_memory_rss:1129560232
used_memory_peak:1129560144
used_memory_peak_human:1.05G
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.00
mem_allocator:libc
loading:0
aof_enabled:0
changes_since_last_save:0
bgsave_in_progress:0
last_save_time:1386600366
bgrewriteaof_in_progress:0
total_connections_received:1
total_commands_processed:0
expired_keys:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:0
keyspace_misses:0
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:0
vm_enabled:0
role:master
db0:keys=4007989,expires=0
```

After I run it when I noticed the memory has decreased in Windows Task Manager, there are not many differences:

```
uptime_in_seconds:4412 (from 69)
lru_clock:248445 (from 248011)
used_cpu_sys:4.59 (from 3.34)
used_cpu_user:10.25 (from 10.06)
used_memory:1129561240 (from 1129560232)
used_memory_human:1.05G (same!)
used_memory_rss:1129561240  (from 1129560232)
used_memory_peak:1129568960 (from 1129560144)
used_memory_peak_human:1.05G (same!)
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.00 (same!)
last_save_time:1386600366 (same!)
total_connections_received:4 (from 1)
total_commands_processed:10 (from 0)
expired_keys:0 (same!)
evicted_keys:0 (same!)
keyspace_hits:0 (same!)
keyspace_misses:2 (from 0)
```

The lookups are taking longer when the memory size is lower. What is going on here?

Comment: How to you see that memory decreases? What is memory consumption from Redis point of view (INFO command)?

Comment: I see it decreasing in Windows Task Manager. I added the output from INFO above.

Comment: So the memory consumed by Redis is 1.05GB not 100MB. I think task manager does not really display the whole memory of the process (but perhaps the private working set, or something similar).

Comment: I just realized I ran this after I reloaded it again. I'm going to wait for it to decrease and re-run INFO again.

Comment: So Redis is still taking the same amount of memory, but it is not accounted anymore in the working set of the process by task manager. Perhaps because part of the memory has been swapped out ...

Comment: You are correct, @DidierSpezia. The memory was being swapped out. If you would like to post this as an answer, I will gladly give you the checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

- What version of Redis are you using ?
- Do you have a cron of some sort that removes key ? (do a grep on the `del` command on your codebase just to be sure)

Comment: I have tired both 2.4.5 and 2.4.6

Comment: I do not have a cron or anything in my codebase that removes keys. I only have gets.

Answer (score 0):

Redis usually runs a single process to manage the in-memory data. However, when the data is persisted to the RDB file, a second process starts to save all the data. During that process, you can see your memory use increase up to double the size of your data set.

I am familiar with how it is done in linux, but I don't know the details about the windows port, so maybe the differences in size you are seeing are because of this second process that is launched periodically? You can easily try if this is the case by issuing a BGSAVE command in redis. This will start the synchronization of data to RDB on the background, so you can see if the memory usage pattern is the one you observed.

If that is the case, then you already know what is going on :)

good luck